# Regular Expression for password validation

Tags: javascript, regex

can any one help me in creating a regular expression for password validation.

The Condition is "Password must contain 8 characters and at least one number, one  letter and one unique character such as `!#$%&? "`

Comment: Password rules are bad. Please see [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation) for more info.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$

---

^.*              : Start
(?=.{8,})        : Length
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])   : Letters
(?=.*\d)         : Digits
(?=.*[!#$%&? "]) : Special characters
.*$              : End
```

Comment: +1 for explanation - tested with a few examples and works at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: i tired with 'acf23!&7h' and its not validating it

Comment: You don't need to put .* at the beginning and end of the match. It's pointless, and will cause significantly worse run times (especially in the case of invalid matches).

Comment: How do I put a `length` limit on this regex?

Comment: Would (?=.*\W|_) work better for symbols if you want to include basically every symbol?

Comment: Using the suggestion from @Tom Lord I modified `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&-+=()!? "]).{8,128}$` which matches a password containing atleast 1 lower case letter, 1 upper case letter, 1 digit and one of the mentioned special characters and which must be between 8 to 128 characters in length.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{6,20})
```

Description of above Regular Expression:

```
(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[\W])        #   must contains at least one special character
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {8,20}  #        length at least 8 characters and maximum of 20 
)           # End of group
```

"/W" will increase the range of characters that can be used for password and pit can be more safe.

Comment: Why do you need all of the (.*)'s? Seems to work fine if you just did: (?=\d*)(?=[a-z]*)(?=[A-Z]*)(?=[\W]*).{6,20}

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve each of the individual requirements easily enough (e.g. minimum 8 characters: `.{8,}` will match 8 or more characters).

To combine them you can use "positive lookahead" to apply multiple sub-expressions to the same content. Something like `(?=.*\d.*).{8,}` to match one (or more) digits with lookahead, and 8 or more characters.

So:

```
(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)(?=.*[!#\$%&\?].*).{8,}
```

Remembering to escape meta-characters.

Comment: You have a few pointless ".*"s in there. You could just use: (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!#\$%&\?]).{8,}

Comment: @TomLord I would want to test that… but you may well be right (reason: of course each positive lookahead only needs to confirm as far as one instance of each type of character).

Comment: Yes, and the main reason I pointed this out is that if your regex does NOT match then it may be made vastly more inefficient to determine this if you include unnecessary ".*"s in there!

Answer (score 6):

Password with the following conditions:

1. At least 1 digit
2. At least 2 special characters
3. At least 1 alphabetic character
4. No blank space

   ```
   'use strict';
   (function() {
       var foo = '3g^g$';

       console.log(/^(?=.*\d)(?=(.*\W){2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s).{1,15}$/.test(foo));

       /**
        * (?=.*\d)         should contain at least 1 digit
        * (?=(.*\W){2})    should contain at least 2 special characters
        * (?=.*[a-zA-Z])   should contain at least 1 alphabetic character
        * (?!.*\s)         should not contain any blank space
        */
   })();
   ```

Comment: hi @nasif-md-tanjim. you don't allow password to contains blank space, why? is bad? bad for what or where?

Comment: @mohammadjawadBarati, just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own regular expression for `javascript` validations;

```
        (/^
        (?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit
        (?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case
        (?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
        [a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}         //should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters

        $/)
```

Example:-   `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
var regularExpression = new RegExp("^^(?=.*[A-Z]{"+minUpperCase+",})" +
    "(?=.*[a-z]{"+minLowerCase+",})(?=.*[0-9]{"+minNumerics+",})" +
    "(?=.*[!@#$\-_?.:{]{"+minSpecialChars+",})" +
    "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$\-_?.:{]{"+minLength+","+maxLength+"}$");
if (pswd.match(regularExpression)) {
    //Success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the pattern below. For more information on the pattern and its explanation, you can refer to the link below.

```
const pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,10}$/;
```

https://medium.com/p/19fc2b2a299c