# Javascript not validating password in Form

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, validation

Hi I have looked around online and I am aware that similar questions have been asked, however, I am unable to find a suitable solution to my problem. I need this code to be password validated, the problem is that I'm not directly working with an `<input>` field therefore I've been unable to figure out how to implement JS.

Here is the HTML (it's implemented using ruby-on-rails, this is all the 'HTML' side that I can see (full code in fiddle below))

```
<form accept-charset='utf-8' method='post' name="form" action='register'  class="registerform" onsubmit="return validate_form()">
<h3 class="registernospace">Contact Information</h3>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td class="registerrowspace" colspan="2">The Password must be at least 6 characters  long and should contain a mixture of lower case letters, upper case letters, and numbers.<br  />The Confirm Password must match the Password.</td></tr>
      <tr><th class="registerrowspace">Password</th><td id="password1" class="registerrowspace"><%= field('password') %></td></tr>
      <tr><th class="registerrowspace">Confirm Password</th><td id="password2" class="registerrowspace"><%= field('password') %></td></tr>
      <tr><th class="registerrowspace">Date of Birth</th><td class="registerrowspace">
   </tbody>
</table>

<% end %>
<input type='hidden' name='register_submitted' value='yes'/>
<p><input type='submit' class="button" value='Register Now' /></p>
</form>
```

And I have tried Implementing some JS (but being unfamiliar with the language I haven't been able to get it working, but I was trying to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate_form()
  {
  var passw = document.getElementById('password1').value;
  if(passw.value.length < 6 ) {
    alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  }
</script>
```

So I was hoping it validates and raises a message if its blank, if its < 6 chars and if it does not include a Uppercase and a number. Although I'm aware I haven't introduced the latter in the code, I couldn't even get the <6 to work.

Also I have other validations (which were built by default which work) and you can see the full:

[Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZE5J/)

[Live Website](http://dchost.co.uk/register)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370015/regular-expression-for-password-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(passw.value.length < 6 ) {
```

should be

```
if(passw.length < 6 ) {
```

because you already get its value

```
var passw = document.getElementById('password1').value;
```

**UPDATE:**

`password1` is `<td>` id not of password feild
i just check your link, it was giving error `passw is undefined in console`, you password field id is `password-input-0`, so use

```
var passw = document.getElementById('password-input-0').value;
```

Comment: I've just tried it on the live website (currently disabled all other validation) and it's not doing anything. I've typed your fix and when I click register, the page refreshes but with no validation? Would you mind taking a look? If not do you have any other ideas? Thanks http://dchost.co.uk/register

Comment: how did you know that was the name of the field? Also if I want to check if password matches the second password box, since both field appear to be called password, is the second password: `password-input-1`?

Comment: thank you so much, I think I can almost fix this, you really saved my ###!

Comment: yes `password-input-1` for second feild, i used firebug for inspect you dom.

Comment: Thank you so much again (I just wanted to make sure it was working before I accepted :). I owe you a pint of the finest Ale! Thanks again Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if(passw.value.length < 6 )` use `if(passw.length < 6 )` you have already value of password you only need to check for size.
Also, Your textfield name is wrong. 'Password1' is td name not password textfield. Please check and correct.

Comment: I've just tried it on the live website (currently disabled all other validation) and it's not doing anything. I've typed your fix and when I click register, the page refreshes but with no validation? Would you mind taking a look? If not do you have any other ideas? Thanks http://dchost.co.uk/register

Comment: Your textfield name is wrong. 'Password1' is td name not password textfield. Please check and correct.

Comment: Thanks for reply. From what I can see, the textfield is 'password'? But would I need to change the js function to document.getElemenetByName instead of by Id? I have just tried and uploaded it to live dchost with 'password' as the textfield and still no luck

Comment: Use document.getElementById('password').value; inspect in firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
if(passw.length < 5 ) //here should be 5
```

Page refreshes when you click the button :you don't call `e.preventDefault();` I think you should listen 'submit' event. In the 'listen' function you may validate the length of the input and prevent it's default behavior.

Comment: I will bare this in mind when I can get it working!... I've tried applying this fix (as mentioned by others below) on the live website (currently disabled all other validation) and it's not doing anything. When I click register, the page refreshes but with no validation? Would you mind taking a look? If not do you have any other ideas? Thanks http://dchost.co.uk/register

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$

---

^.*              : Start
(?=.{6,})        : Length
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])   : Letters
(?=.*\d)         : Digits
(?=.*[!#$%&? "]) : Special characters
.*$              : End



function validatePassword() {
    var newPassword = document.getElementById('changePasswordForm').newPassword.value;
    var regularExpression  = ^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$/;
    alert(newPassword); 
    if(!regularExpression.test(newPassword)) {
        alert("password should contain atleast one number and one special character");
        return false;
    }
}
```