# Regular expression to match at least two special characters in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I have to do jQuery form validation for password.

The password should contain at least two special characters in any order. I have tried with
[Regular Expression for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370015/regular-expression-for-password-validation) but it does not address that two random special characters can come at any order.

How do I do it using a JavaScript regular expression?

Comment: At least two special characters and at least one numeric character:
/^(?=.*\d)(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]){2})(?!.*\s).{6,15}$/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to use look-arounds in cases when you do not have to.

If you only need to make sure the string has at least 2 characters of a specific set, use this kind of a regex (with a negated class to make it more robust):

```
/(?:[^`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'\/.,]*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'\/.,]){2}/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI3eA8/2)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it worked for me:

```
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]){2})/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var goodtogo = false;
var pass = 'simp!le@';   //example
var times = pass.match(/[\\\[\]\/\(\)\+\*\?`!@#$%\^&_=-]/g).length;
if(times >= 2)
    goodtogo = true;
```

Now I advice you to try several passwords and if you find a bug or something don't hesitate to yell back.

And if you have more special chars just add them to the parameter for **match**.

Hope it helps.